# How can I make it so my 3rd-party keyboard shows 'Multiple Languages' instead of just 'English'?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

My third party keyboard supports multiple languages for both autocorrect and the actual app but while selecting it in Settings > General > Keyboard it only shows English under it, unlike other third party keyboards.

How can I change that? And in which .plist do I do it, the keyboard or app?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

in your **keyboard extension .plist**, simply add a "PrimaryLanguage" string field, and add "**mul**". this will change your keyboard language to **Multiple Language** in settings